# Not voting up a correct answer. Is it fair?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting

What should I do when answering a question correctly, but my answer will not accept or voted up .

even no comment from who asked the question about my answer.

What can I do when my answer is ignored.

I think It Is not good idea to mention who asked question in comment to check my answer and I should just wait and double check my answer correct ?

Comment: why down vote ? meta is for these kind of questions !

Comment: Understand that meta works differently. A down-vote here simply means that folks don't agree with your premise, that they feel that it is **not** a good idea to mention in comments for the OP to check your answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You mean. now my question after edit get upvote in meta ?

Comment: I think that the title trumps all. I wouldn't worry about down-votes here though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, please *do not* ask in comments to 'check my answer'. The OP has been notified of your answer the moment you posted, pestering them some more with a comment is not likely to be received well.

If it is really a helpful answer, you'll get upvoted, in time. You cannot force anyone to vote on your answer, let alone to mark it as helpful.

In the meantime, re-read the question. Test your answer yourself. Did you really cover all the bases? Are you sure you didn't miss something? Is there any further documentation or background information you can add?

Also, remember that the best answers are helpful to everyone with the same or similar questions; write your answer for that wider audience! In time, it is that wider audience that'll net you the upvotes anyway.

Comment: Good advice from someone who gets a lot of upvotes.